# Print 2 Dimensional Array in Loop Perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

This is how i append data into the array :

```
push @cordinate_and_link, ($cordinate , $link);
```

So if i print  **@cordinate_and_link** i get something like:

```
172193 1 19601 2 14835 3 4758 4 ...
```

I will like have a loop which can loop only the first column[0] and produce all values.

This is what i have been trying:

```
foreach my $cordinate ( $cordinate_and_link[0]) {
            print "$cordinate";
        }
```

But this statement prints only the last value in the row "4758" as many times as the loop runs.

Comment: what numbers do you want in output?

Comment: @mpapec the first ones, in my case 172193,19601,14835,4758. Which are cordinates. Dont print link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently appending two values to `@cordinate_and_link` which sit next to each other – they are not in separate columns. To make clear that they are in two different columns, we `push` an anonymous arrayref `[...]` instead:

```
push @cordinate_and_link, [$cordinate , $link];
```

Parens `()` do not create arrays or tuples in Perl.

Later, we can loop over all rows and only print the first column in each row:

```
foreach my $cordinate (@cordinate_and_link) {
    print $cordinate->[0];
}
```

Comment: I tried that before but it didnt work:
'Global symbol "@cordinate" requires explicit package name at filename'

Comment: @mpapec You forgot a `->` when accessing the column in `$cordinate`. I also added some explanations

Comment: @amon tnx, I can't type as fast as you. :)

Comment: @mpapec Thanks. Your code works except the omitted ->. I will give you a vote and mark amon as answer since he gave some explanations.

Comment: Oh @amon did not create an answer. You are the answer then. Thanks for the added advice amon

Answer (score 1):

The code in your post flattens your list into a one-dimensional array:

```
push @coordinate_and_link, ($coordinate , $link);
```

which would require a row-major order expression to get at 'column 0'.

I think you want this:

```
push @coordinate_and_link, [$coordinate, $link];
```

In which case you would iterate over it like this:

```
for my $row (@coordinate_and_link) {
    print "$row->[0]\n";
}
```

You can iterate over that structure a lot of ways, that is just one.

EDIT: Fixed typo.